# Como buscar o produto pelo seu titulo?

Tags: php, pdo

Estou tentando fazer a busca pelo titulo do produto, mas independente do titulo consultado, ele sempre me retorna o ultimo registro da tabela Produto.

Estou usando o seguinte código abaixo para executar a busca:

```
<?php
include "conexao.php";
$buscar = $_GET['buscar']; 
$sql=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM produto WHERE titulo LIKE '%".$buscar."%'");
$sql->execute();
foreach($sql->fetchAll() as $res){

echo'
<div id="prod" style="background-color:'.$res["fundosite_cor"].';width:33%; float:left; padding:10px 0;" class="center_prod_box">
    <div align="center" id="titulo" style="width:100%;">
        '.$res["titulo"].'
    </div>
    <div align="center" style="width:100%; height:130px; background-color:'.$res["fundosite_cor"].';">
        <div align="center">
            <a href="prod_detalhe_5.php?codigo='.$res["codigo"].'">
                <img style="width:100%; max-width:100px;" src="img_produtos/'.$res["img01"].'" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div align="center" id="preco" style="width:100%;">
        <span style="">R$ '.$res["preco"].'</span>
    </div>                        
    <div align="center" id="carrinho" style="width:100%;">
        <a href="prod_carrinho.php?acao=add&codigo='.$res["codigo"].'">
            <img style="width:100%; max-width:20px;" src="img/carrinho.png" title="Por no Carrinho" />
        </a>
    </div>                        
 </div>
';
}?>
```

Gostaria de saber como fazer com que ele me retorne o produto relacionado a consulta realizada com o Titulo.

Comment: Utilizar HELP ou AJUDA em titulos de questoes é completamente desnecessario, por favor, evite em perguntas futuras. Leitura recomendada: [ask]

Comment: A ideia de usar *pdo* e *prepared statements* é precisamente não ter que interpolar valores na string que representa a consulta. Logo deveria ser  `LIKE ?` e depois o `execute` receber o valor que vem de `$buscar`, ou até com `bindParam`.

Comment: Não entendi Isac, sou meio leigo, poderia me dar um exemplo de como devo fazer?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.prepare.php